# Matlab: sym.pretty: Too many output arguments

Tags: matlab

I wanted a quick function to speed up typing

```
pretty(simplify(x))
```

So I made a function:

```
function [ret] = ps(input)
    ret = pretty(simplify(input))
end
```

Simple enough. Didn't work:

```
Error using sym.pretty
Too many output arguments.

Error in ps (line 2)
    output_args = pretty(simplify(sym(input_args)))
```

So I split it up:

```
function [ret] = ps(input)
    t1 = sym(input)
    t2 = simplify(t1)
    t3 = pretty(t2)
    ret = t3  
end
```

The result:

```
Error using sym.pretty
Too many output arguments.

Error in ps (line 4)
    t3 = pretty(t2)
```

What gives?

Answer (score 1):

Because [**`pretty()`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/pretty.html) doesn't have any return values.

You should just call it by `pretty(...)`.